Как добавить свою программу в контекстное меню Windows при перетаскивании файла ПКМ?
Допустим, я взял файл/папку правой кнопкой мыши, перетащил в другую папку и отпустил. Появилось контекстное меню:

WinRAR >
Копировать
Переместить
Создать ярлык
Отмена

Я хочу добавить действие моей программы в это меню, как это сделал WinRAR.
Windows 10 Pro x64 ‍‌‍

К счастью, это не так просто. Иначе, половина компов с Windows уже лежали бы. Но рекомендации существуют:

Нажмите клавиши Windows + R, чтобы открыть окно «Выполнить». Введите regedit и нажмите «Ок», чтобы открыть редактор реестра.
В редакторе реестра перейдите по следующему пути: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\Directory\\Background\\shell.
Кликните правой кнопкой мыши по папке Shell и выберите пункт «Создать» — «Раздел». Дайте ему какое-либо имя, например, «notepad».
В правой части редактора реестра дважды кликните по параметру «По умолчанию» и впишите в поле «Значение» желаемое название вашей программы, как оно будет отображаться в контекстном меню.
Кликните правой кнопкой мыши по созданному разделу (в данном случае «notepad») и выберите «Создать» — «Раздел». Назовите раздел «command».
Дважды кликните по параметру «По умолчанию» и введите путь к программе, которую нужно запустить, в кавычках.

После выполнения этих шагов в контекстном меню Проводника появится новый пункт, позволяющий быстро запустить ваше приложение. Обратите внимание, что иногда для применения изменений может потребоваться перезагрузка компьютера.
Если вы используете Windows 11, вы можете использовать бесплатную программу Custom Context Menu для создания своих элементов в новом контекстном меню. Это приложение доступно в Microsoft Store.
Пожалуйста, будьте осторожны при работе с редактором реестра, так как неправильные изменения могут привести к проблемам с системой. Рекомендуется создать резервную копию реестра перед внесением изменений.

"в контекстном меню на рабочем столе появится новый пункт, позволяющий быстро запустить ваше приложение" - это точно отвечает на поставленный вопрос?

Я не претендую на его правильность. Не мой текст. Поскольку здесь нельзя, по-моему, указывать ссылки на внешний источник, я и не указывал. Я взял готовый и вставил. Пусть автор вопроса пробует. Я достаточно опытный пользователь Windows, вижу, что трагедии не будет, если особо не стараться её устроить.
Полагаю, что это у них очепятка, сейчас исправлю.

указывать ссылки на внешний источник здесь можно и нужно, просто они должны сопровождать ответ, а не подменять его )

https://remontka.pro/add-program-context-menu/

Сам я, конечно же, сделал бы такую работу всего один раз. А далее? Для меня нет никакой сложности создать в реестре такие ключи, потом экспортировать созданное в файл .reg, а потом исправлять уже в нём по мере надобности. Проблема не стоит такая просто, неинтересно. Но я работаю с реестром с использованием Python, это возможно.

Это рабочий стол, а не DragAndDrop через ПКМ
